# How to measure the number of clock cycles for memory types in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I am looking for obtaining number of cycles of accessing memory type in CUDA. I want to analyze difference of memory types' and cache types' speed on GPU among the each specific architecture. Is there any source where I can find the number of clock cycles of accessing memory relating to its architecture or is there any method to measure them?

Comment: Have a look at these papers: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06826.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07486.pdf